# SSRS 2017 Error loading QRCoder Version 1.3.6.0

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to show a QRCODE into SSRS, I tested it using QRCoder assembly, It works pretty well on SSRS 2008R2 (QRCoder for .net 3.5), but when I try same at SSRS 2017 it shows an error

```
Error loading code module: 'QRCoder, Version 1.3.6.0,....
```

I tried with different QRCoder.dll versions:

```
net35
net40
netstandard2.0
```

But no one work with it:

I copied QRCoder.dll to this locations for SSRS2017

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MyInstance\R_SERVICES\bin
```

Questions:

What version of QRCoder.dll must use ?

What is the right path to paste QRCoder.dll into my server  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my problem is not CRCoder.dll my problem is the SSRS 2017 bin folder location, looking a little deep into my task manager, and followed the "Reporting services" file location

[image]

And found the right location where must put QRCoder.dll 
[image]

Then for SSRS 2017 bin folder location must look like this

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\bin
```

If U need some help about the full process to show QRCode into SSRS report U can follow this link. (Just a little spanish)

[Print QrCode into SSRS Report ( Spanish  :)](https://www.paradigman.net/index.php/component/content/article/8-soluciones-a-problemas-comunes/13-imprimir-codigo-qr-en-ssrs?Itemid=153)